# Python: return max column from a set of columns

Tags: python, function, max

Let's say i have a dataframe with columns A, B, C, D

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
## create dataframe 100 by 4
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.head(10)
```

I would like to create a new column, "max_bcd", and this column will say 'b','c','d', indicating that for that particular row, one of those three columns contains the largest value.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = ['B', 'C', 'D']
## create dataframe 100 by 4
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.head(10)
df.insert(4, 'max_BCD_name', None)
df.insert(5, 'max_BCD_value', None)
df['max_BCD_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)) # column name
df['max_BCD_value'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[cols].max(axis=1)) # value
print(df)
```

Edit: Just saw your requirement of only B, C and D. Added code for that.

Output:

```
           A         B         C         D max_BCD_name  max_BCD_value
0  -0.653010 -1.479903  3.415286 -1.246829            C       3.415286
1   0.343084  1.243901  0.502271 -0.467752            B       1.243901
2   0.099207  1.257792 -0.997121 -1.559208            B       1.257792
3  -0.646787  1.053846 -2.663767  1.022687            B       1.053846
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this idmax with `axis=1` will help you to find the max value  among columnns:

```
>>> df.idxmax(axis=1)
0    B
1    C
2    D
dtype: object
```